# How to hide div when if condition satisied in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm trying to edit my form In CI.

```
    if($main_content->type=="daily activities"){ ?>
    <script>$("#show_ACTIVITIES").show();</script>
        <?php }
        else{ ?>
 <script>$("#show_ACTIVITIES").hide();</script>

<?php } ?>
```

I want to show div `show_ACTIVITIES` if condition is satisfied if not hide div `show_ACTIVITIES`

Comment: Get rid of **}** close to **<?php }**

Comment: i just tried to minimize the space. in my code i use space like you say

Comment: first check this `if($main_content->type=="daily activities")` is reaching.

Comment: This code will get executed before DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The div will start out showing or hidden, so you don't have to do both.
Still, you should hide the `<div>` by default using `display: "none"`, then have PHP output a JS variable:

```
<script>
var showActivites = <?= $main_content->type=="daily activities" ? "true" : "false" ?>;
</script>
```

Later, in your main JS file, after the DOM has loaded, show the div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (showActivities) $("#show_ACTIVITIES").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if($main_content->type=="daily activities"){ ?>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#show_ACTIVITIES").show();});     </script>
    <?php }
    else{ ?>
 <script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#show_ACTIVITIES").hide();});    </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha Yes he did, so I think this is not a neat way of solving this problem, as this code may end up in the wrong place.